# Recursion help in OCaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I'm trying to make a recursive function with Ocaml, but I keep getting the same error code.

```
let rec get x =
if x > 7 then
get x-7;;
```

And I get the very useful error message of:

> Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of
>   type unit

I'm a complete beginner at OCaml, and studying it for a module at university.
And this is one of my assignments, and I'm a bit stuck!

I originally wanted to do it by a while loop, (as I'm a predominantly imperative programmer), but I couldn't get that to work, so I thought I'd try recursive!

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's two problems with this code. First, the spacing of `x-7` indicates that you would like to pass `x - 7` to `get`, but it will actually be parsed as `(get x) - 7`. That's easily fixed with parentheses:

```
let rec get x =
  if x > 7 then get (x - 7)
```

The second problem is that you don't have a second arm for the `if`, so the function doesn't have much of a chance of returning anything. (One arm `if` is taken to be of type `unit`, only useful for effects.)

You probably want to return something if `x` is less than 7, maybe:

```
let rec get x =
  if x > 7 then get (x - 7) else x
```

Writing this with a while loop is possible, but you should understand that variables in OCaml are not mutable locations, only names. You'll have to introduce and manipulate mutable places explicitly:

```
let get x =
  let y = ref x in
  while !y > 7 do
    y := !y - 7;
  done;
  !y
```

Hope that helps.